# Why does declaring a variable as type int require casting a stream? long type does not require a cast

Tags: java, java-stream

Why does one primitive type require casting and and the other does not?

```
/* This method uses stream operations to count how many numbers in a given array
* of integers are negative
*/    

public static void countNegatives(int[] nums) {
    long howMany = stream(nums) // or: int howMany = (int) stream(nums)
            .filter(n -> n < 0)
            .count();
    System.out.print(howMany);
}
```

Comment: `count()` returns `long` and not every long can fit into an `int`. this is nothing to do with lambda, java-stream nor java-10

Comment: `int i = 5L;` or `long l = 5; int i = l;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*`count()` returns `long` and not every `long` can fit into an `int`* hence an *explicit* cast is required to store the result into an `int`. This is nothing to do with java-10. it's always been there in previous JDK's.

If you don't want to cast then the alternative would be:

```
...
.filter(n -> n < 0)
.map(e -> 1)
.sum();
```

but as one can see this is not as readable as your example because the code essentially says "give me a **summation** of the elements that pass the filter operation" instead of "give me a **count** of the elements that pass the filter operation".

So, ultimately if you need the result as an *int* then go for the cast.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to use `mapToInt` to avoid autoboxing?

Answer (score 6):

The `count()` method of the Java [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) class has been defined to return a `long` value. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--):

> long count()
>   Returns the count of elements in this stream. This is a special case of a reduction and is equivalent to:

```
 return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();
```

In other words, this is how the Java is designed, i.e. it has nothing todo with Lambda.